# Quasi Static Reversibility Theorem

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, terminology, reversibility

As far as I know, the definition of a **reversible process** is simply *"a process that can be reversed"*. Meaning, that for an isolated global system containing the subsystem in question, its thermodynamic variables can hypothetically be restored to their initial values -after reaching their final values- without violating the postulates of Thermodynamics.

The definition of a reversible process is **not** *"a process consisting of an almost infinite number of steps each of which has the global system in almost equilibrium"*, **nor** is it *"a process where the net entropy change of the global system is zero"*.

Those two are proposed statements, and need to be proven equal to the definition by a theorem of some kind.

I ask if anyone could provide me with the deduction of those two statements from the postulates of Thermodynamics.

A few notes:

- Please include very clearly what formulation of the postulates is being used. They can be wildly different.
- For simplicity, I consider an isolated system (for which the first and second postulates apply), which may be subdivided into other sub systems.
- I'm asking about classical thermodynamics, not statistical mechanics.
- In a step of an idealized Quasi Static Process, some thermodynamic variables change by an infinitesimal amount. Yet they add over all of the steps to give a total non-infinitesimal change.
- If the conventional definition of Reversible Process is actually one of the two statements, then the question remains the same, a proof of equivalence of the statements.

Comment: Can you think of a reversible process for which the other two definitions (or really, specifications) do not apply?

Comment: No, I can't. But lack of counter examples is not much of a proof...

Comment: @JuanPerez. Where did you get the statements in the second paragraph.